# How to use data blob in svg image

Tags: image, svg, blob

We can use blob in HTMLImageElement as `<img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/c2159d4d-aaf8-4130-a52c-a49007d17fed">`

What is the equivalent syntax in SVG?

I've tried

```
<svg>
  <image src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/c2159d4d-aaf8-4130-a52c-a49007d17fed"></image>
</svg>
```

and

```
<svg>
  <image xlink:href="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/c2159d4d-aaf8-4130-a52c-a49007d17fed"></image>
</svg>
```

But they didn't work

Comment: Are these inlined in HTML or standalone files?

Comment: SVG images must have width/height attributes.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau it is inlined in HTML

Comment: @rogerz something like `<!doctype html><svg><image xlink:href="blob:..." width="100%" height="100%"/></svg>` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, images in SVG requires width and height attributes to be set explicitly.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width